# problem with ES6 destructuring when migrating to typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I decided to switch my whole puppeteer project to typescript.
One of my files contains the following function:

```
async function hidePopovers(page){
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(()=>{ 
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = '.popover{display: none !important}'; 
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
      let [head] = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
      head.append(style);
  }, 1000);   
  });
}
```

It used to work fine in JS, but TS shows the following problem regarding the line `let [head] = document.getElementsByTagName('head');` :

```
Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLHeadElement>' is not an array type.
```

Now I'm trying to figure out why this problem occured in TS, even though it was just fine in JS, and what I can do to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it's as it says - HTMLCollectionOf is not an array type.

It is array-like though, so you can do something like this:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
const [head] = Array.from(elements);
```

or

```
const [head] = [...document.getElementsByTagName('head')];
```

*EDIT: #2 will only work if downlevelIteration is enabled - OR we are targeting ES2015 or higher.*

This is because TS needs to knows what environment features are available. The iterator protocol requires symbols, which only came in with es6/2015+.

More info here https://mariusschulz.com/blog/downlevel-iteration-for-es3-es5-in-typescript.

**Downlevel iteration (this assumes you're going to provide your own iterator polyfills)**

[image]

**Target higher browser spec**

[image: nt]

Comment: It's not an array, however, it's considered an iterable since it has the `@@iterator` property. [This makes it eligible for array destructuring via `[head] = htmlCollection`](https://jsbin.com/heyamedere/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: First one works, second one shows the same error.
But why did stop working when I switched to TS?

Comment: Added some more explanation @c0rnfl4k3s